# Problema ao atualizar o estado no React ao implementar busca em uma API de Pokémons

Tags: javascript, react

Olá, comunidade do Stack Overflow!

Sou um iniciante em React e decidi criar um pequeno projeto no qual consumo uma API que retorna dados sobre Pokémons. Estou enfrentando problemas ao tentar implementar um mecanismo de busca para filtrar os resultados.

O problema ocorre ao atualizar o estado com os dados recebidos da API. Inicialmente, estou usando o useEffect para montar a URL da API e fazer uma requisição GET. Até aqui, tudo está funcionando corretamente, pois recebo os dados sem problemas.

No entanto, ao tentar atualizar o estado usando useState e definir a variável pokemons, algo não está funcionando como esperado. Eu defini a mudança na query como dependência do useEffect, para que a pesquisa seja executada sempre que uma nova busca for feita. Porém, o estado não está sendo atualizado corretamente.

Aqui está o trecho relevante do meu código:

```
    import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { useSearchParams  } from "react-router-dom"
import Card from "../../Components/Card"

const searchURL = import.meta.env.VITE_SEARCH
const pokemonImage = import.meta.env.VITE_GET_IMAGE

const Search = () => {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams()
  const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState([])
  const query = searchParams.get("q")

  
  const PokemonImageURL = (index) => {
    return `${pokemonImage}${index}.png` 
  }  
  
  

  useEffect(() => {

      const searchWithQueryURL = `${searchURL}${query}`;
     
      const getSearchedPokemons = async (url) => {
        const res = await fetch(url)
        const data = await res.json()
        setPokemons(data)
      }
      getSearchedPokemons(searchWithQueryURL)
      
    }, [query])
    
    console.log(pokemons)
  return (
      <div className="container">
        <h2 className="title"> Resultados para: <span className="query-text"> {query} </span> </h2>
        <div className="pokemon-container">
            {pokemons.length === 0 && <p> Carregando </p>}
            {pokemons.map((pokemon, index) => (
                <div key={index}>
                    <Card
                        name={pokemon.forms[0].name}
                        id={pokemon.id}
                        img={PokemonImageURL(index)}
                        url={pokemon.forms[0].url}
                    >

                        
                    </Card>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
        </div>
  )
  
  }

export default Search
```

Se você quiser examinar o código completo do projeto, você pode acessar o repositório no GitHub [aqui](https://github.com/leonardorimes/pokeSearch).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Somente olhando o código não parece ter nada de errado mas o react é bem traiçoeiro nesse quesito.
Você pode simplificar bastante o seu `useEffect`:

```
const keys = Object.keys(pokemons)

useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    console.log('searching new pokemons')
    const data = await fetch(`${searchURL}${query}`).json()
    console.log('search result', data)

    // quando for definir o state sempre utilize uma function 
    // isso para alguns bugs muito difíceis de encontrar
    // da uma olhada aqui: https://youtu.be/GGo3MVBFr1A?t=177
    setPokemons(() => data)
  })()
}, [query])

....
<div className="pokemon-container">
  {keys.length === 0 && <p> Carregando </p>}
  {keys.map(key => {
    const pokemon = pokemons[key]

    return (
      <Card
        key={key}
        name={pokemon.forms[0].name}
        id={pokemon.id}
        img={PokemonImageURL(index)}
        url={pokemon.forms[0].url}
      />
    )
  }}
</div>
```

Tirando os comentários e os logs você terá uma função com duas linhas apenas e, pela minha experiência com react, isso vai funcionar e atualizar corretamente seu state.

Comment: As suas dicas foram muito preciosas, obrigado pelo vídeo que compartilhou. Mas fiz as modificações e no console aparece o seguinte: pokemons.map is not a function. Entendo que ele esteja tentando interar no array vazio. Será que é aquela dependência "query"? obrigado pela ajuda amigo

Comment: O log do 'search result' apresentou algum dado? Provavelmente esse valor está como undefined aí causa esse erro

Comment: apresentou sim, todo o objeto json com os dados do pokémon. Estou achando muito estranho

Comment: porém ele recebe somente um objeto, não um array de objetos. Pode ser esse o erro?

Comment: exatamente isso. `map` é um método somente para arrays. nesse caso você tem duas opções: 1- reestruturar seu backend para te enviar um array ao invés de um object (ou talvez o problema seja esse `.json()`, vale o teste também).  2 - utilizar o `Objects.keys` e continuar utilizando o map.

Comment: que treta, kkkk. Confesso que dei uma viajada, vou precisar dar uma pesquisada nesses itens que me passou.

Comment: No caso o backend é uma api publica que fornece os dados, então a opção 2 parece ser a mais adequada

Comment: editei minha resposta pra mostrar melhor como usar o Object.keys

Comment: Amigo depois de seus comentários e ajuda consegui resolver. Obrigado pela moral

Comment: fico feliz em ajudar :D Se puder marcar minha resposta como a solução da pergunta me ajuda também ;)